# why dictionary of american idioms says "of is usually retained before pronouns"

Tags: prepositions

why dictionary of american idioms says "of is usually retained before pronouns" such as order someone off ((of)something) to command someone to get off something.(Of is usually retained before pronouns) The teacher ordered Tom off of his steps

Comment: The dictionary is talking about the difference between *off (of) his steps* and *off (of) them*. Here, *them* is a pronoun, and *his steps* are not.

Comment: thanks, but some examples like "of his steps" exist in other parts of the dictionary.

Comment: In response to your comment, the dictionary doesn't say that *of* is usually dropped before non-pronouns. It says it is usually retained before pronouns. According to the dictionary, then, Americans can say either *I ordered Tom off of the roof* or *I ordered Tom off the roof,* but when we replace *roof* with *it*, we usually say  *I ordered Tom off of it.* Is the dictionary right about this? More or less ... *I ordered Tom off it* sounds more informal to me than *I ordered Tom off of it*, but I wouldn't consider it ungrammatical.

Comment: thank you very much